# Do not replace existing file when uploading file with same name Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

How can I prevent replacing the existing file with a new file which has the same name, when I upload file to one drive?
I am using `PUT /me/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#http-request-to-upload-a-new-file) end point.
I instead need to keep indexing (test.jpg, test (1).jpg) or, just like google drive does, add two files with the same name.
[image]

Comment: It looks like by design to me. If i am not wrong, this is nothing to do with the Onedrive API. I tried opening my onedrive manually, tried upload the same file from my physical drive to Onedrive. It thrown me the prompt "A file with this name already exists. Would you like to add this new file as the latest version of the existing file?". You can consider filing uservoice to see whether this idea can be considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control this behavior using [Instance Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#instance-attributes), specifically the `@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior` query parameter. There are three supported conflict behaviors; `fail`, `replace` (the default), and `rename`.

> The conflict resolution behavior for actions that create a new item. You can use the values fail, replace, or rename. The default for PUT is replace. An item will never be returned with this annotation. Write-only.

In order to have it automatically rename the file, you add `@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior=rename` as a query parameter to your URI.

```
PUT /me/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content?@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior=rename
```